# Configure a default profile on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, gnome-shell, users, user-profile, skel

How can I set a default profile on Ubuntu 20.04 for all newly created users?

I used to use `/etc/skel`, but it doesn't work anymore, except for `.bashrc` or `.profile`. Indeed, if I copy the `.mozilla` folder to `/etc/skel`, it is not copied when a new user logs in.  I would also like to remove the welcome windows that you have to pass: geolocation, livepatch...

Thanks to all of you!

Comment: "it is not copied when a new user logs in."  ehm "/etc/skel" is for when a new user is CREATED.  You want "/etc/profile".

Comment: To be precise, new users come from an LDAP directory.
I don't know /etc/profile.d/, it replaces /etc/skel. Is there a tutorial somewhere?

Comment: " it replaces /etc/skel" It does not replace it. /etc/profile is examined as the 1st part of the login process and holds instructions applicable to all users. At the end of it it will source a file in the home directory so the login continues with user specific instructions.